# Erro na instalação, Mysql server dando falha

Tags: mysql, instalador

Resetei o meu pc recentemente, agora que estou fazendo a instalação do Mysql pelo intaller community todos os serviços são instalados com exceção do Mysql server.
já foi instalado a versão 2010, 2013 e 2015-2019 do microsoft visual c++, porem não funciona [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já vi isso acontecer quando o instalador do mysql é x64 bits e o microsoft visual c++ é x86, ou vice versa. Baixe os dois instaladores x86 e teste.

Comment: Cara Amanda, verifique duas coisas, se já existe o mysql server instalado no painel de controle, caso contrário vá na pasta "arquivos de programas" (geralmente c:\programs and files e/ou c:\programs and files (x86)) e procure pela pasta mysql (creio que programa), se existir é porque houve uma instalação anterior que "falhou" ou seu windows foi restaurado e ficou vestígios. No entanto é bem mais provável que você tenha instalado o mysql-workbanch que já vem com mysqlserver.